# Vega-lite: Line chart. start line mark from the y-axis domain line

Tags: javascript, charts, vega-lite, vega

I have a line graph.
I wanted the lines to start from the y-axis only. Currently the line is starting after a break.

This is the original graph:
https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/dcc9afece4dc6a5e89835650ec607280/og_chart.json

This is the chart in which I tried to get the change:

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/e99bd5bd778e63af42bbbe6757301523/change_og_chart.json

This is the current chart

[image]

I would like to change this so the lines start from the y-axis only.
[image]

How could I shift the grid lines to the right to start with the y-axis domain line or is there a better way to start the line from the domain line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "60": 100,
        "90": 150,
        "120": 200,
        "-120": 10,
        "-90": 15,
        "-60": 30,
        "type": "Mango"
      },
       {
        "-120": 50,
        "-90": 30,
        "-60": 45,
        "60": 90,
        "90": 140,
        "120": 190,
        "type": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["-120", "-90", "-60", "60", "90", "120"]}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "key",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "sort": null,
          "axis": {"tickCount": 10, "values": [-120,-90,-60,0,60,90,120],
          "labelExpr": "abs(datum.value)"}
        },
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "maroon",
        "size": 3,
        "strokeDash": [6, 4]
      },
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0, "bandPosition": 0}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you again! One last question. The gridlines are not evenly spaced for some reason. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: It's because it is a continuous axis. There are a line of numbers from -120 to +120 and your 60,90,120 values plot on that line. The gap between 0 to 60 is obviously larger than the gap between 60 to 90 and 90 to 120.

Comment: Understood. I really can't thank you enough for your help in my every query. Really helped me get the resolution faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are using discrete x-axis (bands) rather than continuous. I would do something like this.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "pre_120": 10,
        "pre_90": 15,
        "pre_60": 30,
        "post_60": 100,
        "post_90": 150,
        "post_120": 200,
        "type": "Mango"
      },
      {
        "pre_120": 50,
        "pre_90": 30,
        "pre_60": 45,
        "post_60": 90,
        "post_90": 140,
        "post_120": 190,
        "type": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "key",
            "bandPosition": 0,
            "axis":{ "bandPosition":0, "labelOffset":-55},

          "sort": [
            "pre_120",
            "pre_90",
            "pre_60",
            "0",
            "post_60",
            "post_90",
            "post_120"
          ],
          "scale": {
            "domain": [
              "pre_120",
              "pre_90",
              "pre_60",
              "0",
              "post_60",
              "post_90",
              "post_120"
            ]
          }
        },
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "maroon",
        "size": 3,
        "strokeDash": [6, 4]
      },
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": "0", "bandPosition": 0}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible that the extra space on the right of the chart also get truncated so the lines also touch the boundary instead of stopping while hanging in the air??

Comment: I'll have to have a think. The problem is you're using a band scale rather than a continuous scale which is typical for a line chart. Could your axis values be -120, -90, +90, +120 etc?

Comment: How could the problem be solved if that was the case?

Comment: Because then it would be a continuous axis. You are using a band scale as described here at the moment. https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html

Comment: Honestly,  I have no control over it. as the data comes from an external source. Is there any way the issue could be resolved with this data structure only?

Comment: I'll add another answer to show you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 800,
  "height": 200,
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "60": 100,
        "90": 150,
        "120": 200,
        "-120": 10,
        "-90": 15,
        "-60": 30,
        "type": "Mango"
      },
       {
        "-120": 50,
        "-90": 30,
        "-60": 45,
        "60": 90,
        "90": 140,
        "120": 190,
        "type": "Apple"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["-120", "-90", "-60", "60", "90", "120"]}],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "key",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "sort": null,
          "axis": {"tickCount": 10, "values": [-120,-90,-60,0,60,90,120]}
        },
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "maroon",
        "size": 3,
        "strokeDash": [6, 4]
      },
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 0, "bandPosition": 0}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I had a query regarding this. I was adding the number 7 in front of the number so that I could split them in label expression in this way: [-2120,-290,-260,20,260,290,2120]. and the label expression:"axis": {"labelExpr": "split(datum.label, '7')[1]"}. But the chart is changing when I add the number. I have added the screenshit in the question above

Comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to do. The gridlines are where they are because the axis is continuous and so cannot be "shifted".

Comment: The gridline issue is resolved thanks to your second answer. The next issue is what the labels should look like in the x-axis. The labels should be 120, 90, 60, 0, 60, 90,120. I was having trouble in writing those in the chart

Comment: Sorry - still not following. The labels already say 120, 90, 60, 0, 60, 90,120 don't they?

Comment: I have to remove the minus sign from the labels in the x-axis.

Comment: I see. I'll add another answer for you shortly.

Comment: Done. You can use abs() function to remove the sign.